# Parsing directory of files line by line for error messages

Tags: c#

I have the code below that searches a directory (z:), it returns all the files for yesterday, I need to read through this list of today files then line by line and search for any error messages, if I find any error messages in a file, I want to write out the file name followed by the error message that is in the file, the error can contain different nos of lines.

The first issue I am having is when I try to read the list of today files with File.ReadLines(file); it doesn’t like this and then I also need to format writing the file name followed by the error message and the different no of lines it can contain.

The files are in the .htm format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace NetworkSearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

                FileInfo[] todaysFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"z:\")
                          .EnumerateFiles()
                          .Select( x => {
                          x.Refresh();
                          return x;
                          })
                         .Where( x => x.CreationTime.Date == today ||      x.LastWriteTime >= today )
                         .ToArray()
                         ;

                string fileName = @"D:\Temp\Network.txt";

                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))

                foreach (FileInfo file in todaysFiles)
                {
                    File.ReadLines(file);
                    if (line.Contains("ERROR"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
                        sw.WriteLine(file); //file name
                        sw.WriteLine(errLine);  //errline can contain diff nos of lines
                        sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
                    }
                 }
             }
             catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
             {   
                Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
             }
             catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in todaysFiles)
    {
        var errorLines = File.ReadLines(file.FullName).Where(l => l.Contains("ERROR")).ToList();
        if (errorLines.Any())
        {
            sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
            sw.WriteLine(file.Name); //file name
            foreach (var errLine in errorLines)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(errLine);
            }
            sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File.ReadLines return `IEnumerable<string>`. To get a line out of it you have to loop through. And it takes a `string path` as argument, not `FileInfo`.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in todaysFiles)
    {
        foreach(string line = File.ReadLines(file.FullName));
        {
            if (line.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                string errLine = "my error";

                sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
                sw.WriteLine(file.Name); //file name
                sw.WriteLine(errLine);  //errline can contain diff nos of lines
                sw.WriteLine("----- ERROR -----");
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help stefankmitph